# Register - Login to laravel with social accounts not working

Tags: php, facebook, laravel

I'm using socialite to allow my users register and login with their social accounts such as, `Facebook, Twitter, Google+` but it doesn't work, will give this error:

[image: error]

here is my `LoginController`

```
public function redirectToProvider()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
    }

    public function handleProviderCallback()
    {
      try{
        $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
        $user->token;
      } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return redirect()->intended('jobseekers/login');
      }
      $authUser = $this->findOrCreate($user);

      Auth::login($authUser, true);
      return redirect()->intended('jobseekers');
    }

    public function findOrCreate($facebookUser)
    {
      $authUser = User::where('id', $facebookUser->id)->first();

      if($authUser)
      {
        Session::flash('success', 'Welcome, You are successfully Registered with your Facebook account');
        return $authUser;
      }

      return User::create([
        $user->id = $facebookUser->id,
        $user->first_name = $facebookUser->name,
        $user->last_name  = $facebookUser->name,
        $user->image = $facebookUser->avatar,
        $user->email  = $facebookUser->email,
      ]);
    }
```

PS: code above will not register users and return errors but before that I used code below and it register users but will not give them password so they weren't be able to login that was the reason why I changed code below to code above:

```
public function redirectToProvider()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
    }

    public function handleProviderCallback()
    {
        $userSocial = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();

        $findUser = User::where('email', $userSocial->email)->first();
        if ($findUser) {
          Auth::login($findUser);
            return redirect()->route('user.index');
        }else{
              $user = new User;
              $user->id = $userSocial->id;
              $user->first_name = $userSocial->name;
              $user->last_name  = $userSocial->name;
              $user->image = $userSocial->avatar;
              $user->email  = $userSocial->email;
              $user->save();
              Auth::login($user);
              Session::flash('success', 'Welcome, You are successfully Registered with your Facebook account');
              return redirect()->route('user.index');
        }
    }
```

before code above I used

**Update:**

If i remove `else{ ... }` from my code user will register but same as my second code without password, so user is not able to login.

Comment: What is the line 74 in `LoginController` ?

Comment: @SauminiNavaratnam Doesn't exist! I only have 70 lines! here is my logincontroller you can see my codes. https://gist.github.com/robertnicjoo/35ab429fb570b94dc911e525b7be5ca6

Comment: Looks like the exception is thrown for your previous code, because the stack says `findOrCreate` at line 57, but the link to code doesn't have. Can you check you are looking the right file

Comment: @SauminiNavaratnam look in where? PS: I updated my question please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, here is final code:

```
public function handleProviderCallback()
    {
        try {
            $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->fields([
            'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'gender'
        ])->scopes(['first_name', 'last_name'])->user();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return redirect()->route('user.index');
        }

        $authUser = $this->findOrCreateUser($user);

        Auth::login($authUser, true);

        return redirect()->route('jobseeker.profile');
    }

    /**
     * Return user if exists; create and return if doesn't
     *
     * @param $facebookUser
     * @return User
     */
    private function findOrCreateUser($facebookUser)
    {
        $authUser = User::where('fb_id', $facebookUser->id)->first();

        if ($authUser){
            return $authUser;
        }
        return User::create([
            'fb_id' => $facebookUser->id,
            'first_name' => $facebookUser->user['first_name'],
            'last_name'  => $facebookUser->user['last_name'],
            'username' => $facebookUser->user['last_name'],
            'avatar' => $facebookUser->avatar,
            'email'  => $facebookUser->email,
            'gender' => $facebookUser->user['gender'],
        ]);

    }
```